# Repo.js not showing up in my HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, github, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use [Repo.js](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js) for embedding a github repo into my HTML this is what I've tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="As my favourite director, Billy Wilder said; If a movie makes you forget for a second
that you didn’t park the car properly, or that you argued with your boss… Then it fulfilled its goal.
">
    <meta name="keywords" content='pawelpawlowski,petersellers,montgomeryclift'>
    <title>Movie Torrents</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="repo.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" />
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js/master/repo.min.js" />
     <script>
    $(function() {
        $('body').repo({ user: 'pablobiedma', name: 'movie-torrents' })
    });
</script> 
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="foto.png" />
</head>
<body>
                <div id="particles-js"></div>

        <header>
        
      

                <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="english.html">Home</a>
  <a href="https://letterboxd.com/pablobiedma/films/reviews/"target="_blank">Movie Reviews</a>
  <a href="https://www.imdb.com/list/ls049315410/"target="_blank">My Favourite Movies</a>
  <a href="torrent.html" class="active">Movie Torrents</a>
  <a href="filmmate.html">Filmmate</a>
  <a href="index.html">Spanish</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
  
</div>
                        
</header>

<div class="texto">
                <h2 class="texto">Movie Torrents</h2></div>
        </div>
   
</body>

</html>
```

The repo is not showing up, you can only see this: [image]
What am I doing wrong, please I don't know too much about javascript or jquery so sorry if my mistake is too stupid because I've no clue what to do/dowload in order to make this work.

Comment: You have at least one serious error that a validator such as https://validator.nu/ would highlight.

Comment: Also raw.github is not a CDN. It will claim your JS is plain text which will prevent some browsers from executing it. Get real web hosting.

Comment: okay I fixed the validator.nu errors, @Quentin it is still now showing up, do you think it would under a real web hosting?

Comment: no, it's not there yet, http://cibercinema.com/torrent.html @Quentin

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Read the error messages. Failing that, look at the Network tab and make sure all your dependencies are loading.